# Synchronization object required when modifying elements stored in concurrent container?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a simple class:

```
public class TaskResult
{
    public TaskResult()
    {
        CompletedSoFar = 0;
        Done = false;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public int CompletedSoFar { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public bool Done { get; set; }   
}
```

and objects of its type are stored in ConcurrentDictionary:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, TaskResult> _results;
```

and used like:

```
public TaskResult DoWork(int[] ids)
{
    var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var result = new TaskResult();
    _results[Guid.NewGuid()] = result;

    var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                cancelSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                // Do work...
                result.CompletedSoFar++; // Increment work completed so far
            }

            result.Done = true; // Work now done
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }, cancelSource.Token);

    return result;
}
```

Can I modify values (i.e. CompletedSoFar, Done) without a synchronization object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to, does it throw an exception? Since you are modifiying a native-type (integer) I would not expect exceptions, these types cannot be locked and can be safely accessed on multiple threads. However, you should be careful with changing such (status) types in multiple threads since this could change the behaviour in unexpected ways and can be very hard to trace

Comment: No exceptions are thrown when modifying them.

Comment: Then you can (technically) do this, but I would advice you to (if possible) create some "synchronization object" that can manage (block/allow) changes to this specific object and that is able (for debugging purposes) to store the changes and the callers. Futhermore, if you would want to change other non-native types this object would come in handy, so it is a good-practice for code-extensibility